# Replace header in a csv file python with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to replace header string of my `csv` file with pandas libraries, but i can't understand how can I do this.

I try to see `DataFrame` but i don't see anything to do this.
anyone can help me?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by replace header? Do you mean skip when importing? or read, change then write back out?

Comment: Ok i've found DataFrame.replace method and it works!

Answer (score 1):

From a glance at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), it looks like it would be something like

```
df = pandas.Dataframe.read_csv(filename, ...)
new_header = ['new', 'column', 'names'] 
df.to_csv(new_filename, header=new_header, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Reading `csv` files in Pandas

There are many [options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) available when reading `csv` files.  Here are some examples:

```py
import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO

fake_csv_file = '''Col1,Col2,Col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9'''

print 'Original CSV:'
print fake_csv_file
print

print 'Read in CSV File:'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fake_csv_file))
print df
print

print 'Read in CSV File using multiple header lines:'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fake_csv_file), header=[0,1])
print df
print

print 'Read in CSV File ignoring header rows:'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fake_csv_file), skiprows=2)
print df
print
```

---

```
Original CSV:
Col1,Col2,Col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9

Read in CSV File:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6
2     7     8     9

Read in CSV File using multiple header lines:
  Col1 Col2 Col3
     1    2    3
0    4    5    6
1    7    8    9

Read in CSV File ignoring header rows:
   4  5  6
0  7  8  9
```

## Writing `csv` files in Pandas

There are many [options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) available when writing `css` files.  Take careful note at the placement of commas in the final output in some the code below. Here are some examples:

```py
# Set DataFrame back to original
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fake_csv_file))

print 'Write out a CSV file:'
print df.to_csv()
print

print 'Write out a CSV file with different headers:'
print df.to_csv(header=['COLA','COLB','COLC'])
print

print 'Write out a CSV without the pandas added index:'
print df.to_csv(index=False)
print
```

---

```
Write out a CSV file:
,Col1,Col2,Col3
0,1,2,3
1,4,5,6
2,7,8,9


Write out a CSV file with different headers:
,COLA,COLB,COLC
0,1,2,3
1,4,5,6
2,7,8,9


Write out a CSV without the pandas added index:
Col1,Col2,Col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

#### Notes:

1. `StringIO` and inline text is for example only.  Normally, to read a specific file you'd use

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
   ```
2. [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) without a file is used for example only.  Normally, to write a specific file you'd use

   ```
   df.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
   ```